# What is the formula for momentum in a lab reference frame?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, momentum, collision

When learning momentum in introductory physics, I was taught this formula: $m_1 v_{1i}+m_2 v_{2i}=m_1 v_{1f}+m_2 v_{2f}$.

However, my new calculus-based textbook states advises to use the formula $v_{1f}=\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_{1i}+\frac{2m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_{2i}$ in any reference frame that is not the center of mass reference frame.

When I try to apply the formula $m_1 v_{1i}+m_2 v_{2i}=m_1 v_{1f}+m_2 v_{2f}$ in a lab reference frame, my answer comes out very different than the answers provided by the answer keys.

Why is this? Is the formula I learned in introductory physics incorrect, and if not, why doesn't it work properly in lab frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first formula is the total momentum of the system which does not change, On the left-hand side is the expression for the *before* impact momentum, and on the right-hand side the *after* impact momentum. The two are equal, regardless of the reference frame, as long as the observer is in an inertial frame (fixed, or moving with steady speed).

The second formula is *a specific result* in a particular collision problem (not specified in the question). If you assume the two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ exchange some measure of momentum, called the impulse $J$, then you can write the momentum of each body *after* as a function of the momentum *before*.

$$ \begin{aligned}
  m_1 v_{1f} & = m_1 v_{1i} - J \\
  m_2 v_{2f} & = m_2 v_{2i} + J 
\end{aligned} \tag{1}$$

See how the impulse $J$ is added or subtracted in equal measure for the two bodies due to Newton's 3rd law.

The result of the operation above *does not change the total momentum* because while one body gets added $J$ momentum, the other body gets subtracted $J$ momentum. Check for yourself $$ m_1 v_{1f} + m_2 v_{2f} = (m_1 v_{1i} -J) + (m_2 v_{2i} + J) = m_1 v_{1i} + m_2 v_{2i} \tag{2}$$

Now use the law of collision that relates the **relative** velocity of the two bodies *after* impact, to the **relative** velocity *before* impact to find the value $J$ and thus solve for the final motions.

For example for elastic collisions, the condition that the bounce is equal in magnitude but opposite in direction as the impact is expressed as $ (v_{1f}-v_{2f}) = - (v_{1i}-v_{2i})$ which results in the following impulse magnitude from (1).

$$ J =2 \tfrac{m_1 m_2}{m_1 + m_2} (v_{1i}-v_{2i}) \tag{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

You are clearly learning physics (good!). A very important lesson is that the physics is in the derivation of the formula, not in the result! So quoting the formula without knowing where it came from is a bad plan.

The formulae you quote express different physics. The first formula (from your 'introductory' text book) expresses the law of conservation of momentum in a two-particle situation (in one dimension: it generalises to three dimensions if we use the vector velocity $\mathbf{v}$). So it can't fail! But on its own it can't solve for the final velocities in terms of the initial velocities, because there are two of them and only one equation. However the second formula appears to do just that! How did it do it?

The answer is it also contains conservation of kinetic energy in the collision. This is not so general because kinetic energy is not necessarily conserved, because the energy could transform into some other form. Collisions that conserve kinetic energy are called elastic.

I can't answer whether the second formula applies in your problem because you didn't quote the problem. But it's more important that *you* make that decision having understood the different physics in the two formulae.

Comment: I don't think the second formula uses conservation of kinetic energy; this is the derivation:

Let $v$ be the relative velocity between frames, $v_{1f}$ the lab frame, and $v'_{1f}$ the cm frame.

$$v_{1f}=v'_{1f}+v$$
(substituting condition for elastic collisions)
$$=-v'_{1i}+v$$ 
$$=-(v_{1i}-v)+v\\=-v_{1i}+2\frac{m_1 v_{1i}+m_2 v_{2i}}{m_1+m_2}\\=\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}+2\frac{m_1 v_{1i}+m_2 v_{2i}}{m_1+m_2}$$

I'm just unclear as to why the second formula seems to always work for problems, regardless of which reference frame, but the first one only works in the cm frame?

Comment: Oh yes it does use conservation of energy!! It's in the first line where the final velocity in the COM frame is set to minus the initial velocity: that's the definition of an elastic, or kinetic energy-conserving, collision. As for the first formula, as I said it cannot solve the problem on its own, because it is one equation with two unknowns. If you are using that you must be using some other equation as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean "comes out very different".

Can you show more work?
How are you using this in your specific problem (in the lab frame and in the c.o.m. frame)?

(I presume your collision is elastic [i.e. the case when total kinetic-energy is conserved].)
Note that there is another formula for $v_{2f}$ that you do not have.
This might be the reason you have conflicting answers.

Comment: Maybe! What is the other formula for $v_{2f}$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the collisions were all elastic. I did a momentum worksheet, and any of the questions that weren't in the c.o.m. frame used the second formula. 

My answers where I used the first formula in a lab frame were all incorrect. I want to understand why the first formula only works in the c.o.m. reference frame.